# replace ID in the txt file and generate multiple txt output

Tags: r

I have a sample txt file. I want to replace the ID (for example ABC) in the sample txt file with a list of IDs (001, 002, ....n) and output multiple txt files.
Here is the code in R.

```
  ids=read.delim("ids.txt",header = F)
  txt1 <- readLines("sample.txt")
  for (i in ids$V1){
   writeLines(gsub("\\bABC\\b", i, txt1), paste0(i, ".txt"))
  }
```

However, it only successfully replaces ABC alone with 001 but failed to replace ABC_base to 001_base.
Any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word boundaries are stopping it from replacing it from `'ABC_base'` with `'001_base'`.

Try the following :

```
for (i in ids$V1){
  writeLines(gsub("ABC", i, txt1), paste0(i, ".txt"))
}
```